# How I can solve Object has no method 'appendChild'

Tags: javascript

my problem is that when you run the code in the console shows this: **object has no method 'appendChild'**

This is my code:

```
    function createColumns() {

    var nodesTr = document.getElementsByTagName( 'tr' );

    for( var i in nodesTr ) {

        if( i < 3 || i == 8 || i == 13 || i == 15 || i == 18 )
            continue;

        for( var j = 1; j <= 14; j++ ) {

            var nodeHTML = document.createElement( 'td' );
            nodeHTML.innerHTML = 1;
            nodesTr[ i ].appendChild( nodeHTML );

        }   // end for

    }   // end for

} // end function createColumns
```

the problem is in this part

```
nodesTr[ i ].appendChild( nodeHTML );
```

Comment: Can you please put html and js in jsfiddle?

Comment: why don't you use insertCell instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're using `for-in` instead of a `for` statement

This will hit properties that are not nodes:

```
for( var i in nodesTr ) {
```

---

You can verify this by using `console.log()` to log your values.

```
console.log(i, nodesTr[ i ]);
```

I believe it will hit the `.length` property, and perhaps the `.item()` method.

---

Using a `for` statement will only iterate numeric indices, and will guarantee that the order is what you defined in the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodesTr.length; i++) {
```